# ms teams bot command menu alternative to mobile clients

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams

I have a simple bot that uses [bot command menu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-commands-menu?tabs=dotnet).

It mentions that

> Bot menus won't appear on mobile clients.

- How do i replicate the bot Menu for mobile clients ?
- I have looked into [messaging extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/what-are-messaging-extensions) but they seem like
  overkill and complex. Is it the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So these menus are really nice on desktop, but all they're really doing is filling words into the textbox to save the user some typing - at the end of the day, the user can still type them in by hand, or type in anything else they choose to.

If you really want to give the user some guidance / options on what commands they can do by text, you can do this using a Welcome message (see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)). In addition, instead of a plain text message, you can send an [Adaptive Card](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-cards), which can include buttons the user can click on, and these work on all platforms. Here's [an excellent article on cards](https://poszytek.eu/en/microsoft-en/microsoft-adaptive-cards-the-ultimate-guide/), and see the image at the end of the post for the final card.